# Microsoft Charts for .Net 4, Pie chart appearance

Tags: c#, .net, mschart, pie-chart

How can I show in the label both the percentage and the name eg. "winners 32%" and "losers 68%". I currently have just a percentage showing using the following code:

```
Chart1.Series[0].Label = "#PERCENT{P0}";
```

Comment: http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=1132 check this out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simply this:

```
Chart1.Series[0].Label = "#VALX #PERCENT{P0}";
```

'#VALX' shows the x value and so combining with the '#PERCENT{P0}' generates a label like this "winners 32%" where "winners" is my x value.