# how to display a value associated with a slice in piechart in percentage.

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I want to display values associated with each slice of the pie chart in percentage format, but can't find a way to do it. All i found was if you make "IsValueShownAsLabel" property as true it shows the value associated with the slice, but not in percentage format. i also want to display names associated with each slice outside the piechart and not within it (as is with default case).
This is my first time using piecharts so don't know much about it's properties. Kindly help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which charting API you're using. *Assuming* you're using MSChart, maybe the information in this question will help?

[Microsoft Charts for .Net 4, Pie chart appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513628/microsoft-charts-for-net-4-pie-chart-appearance)